# how to implement drag and drop like shortcuts which developed by apple?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I know how to enable drag and drop for tableview in iOS. But the default behavior of it looks strange. User must press a cell for a long time to enable drag. I have read some answers said that changed the `minimumPressDuration` to 0.1. I had tried this way, but I don't think it's good enough.
What I want likes `shortcuts app` showed which is simulously.

Comment: just search for drag-drop api

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I had looked many articles and apis for drag-drop, both private api. But I didn't find anything helped. I try to implement by custom `UIDrapInteraction` , but I found that I can't change the time for recognizer either.